# VBA Copy Paste causing Shapes to Multiply

Tags: excel, vba

The below code copies the first row from a sheet named 'Template' to the first row of all other sheets in the workbook.

The Template should only be the source and not also a destination for the copied row.

The first row on the Template sheet contains values, and shapes and command buttons with assigned macros. All need to be copied to all sheets.

This seemed to be working, however I discovered after a while that there were hundreds of the same shape/button on each sheet stacked on top of each other. The source sheet 'Template' was also affected in the same way.

How do I exclude 'Template' as a destination and prevent the shapes/buttons from multiplying on all sheets?

```
Sub UpdateHeaderRow()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim HeaderRow As Range
    Set HeaderRow = Worksheets("Template").Range("1:1")
    HeaderRow.Copy
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Range(HeaderRow.Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            ws.Paste
    Next ws
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You're also pasting back into "Template" in your loop, since you don't exclude that sheet?

Comment: Add. .. `If ws.Name <> "Template" Then` after  `For each` statement and `End if` before `Next ws` statement

Comment: @naresh Thanks that excluded Template but the shapes still multiply on all other sheets. Any idea what the problem could be here?

Comment: No.. This code works fine for me.

Comment: The thing is you don't actually notice there are multiples of the same shape unless you start deleting them one at a time to reveal the one beneath, or view the shapes and buttons in the "Selection Pane", which shows the very long list of objects created. The "Selection Pane" must be viewed for each individual sheet to see the objects on it. "Template" sheet will not show multiples.

Comment: Are there multiple shapes in template sheet row 1? .. Are you using this macro as standalone or through some other macro?.. Have you deleted all the extra shapes those were added earlier?.. To delete all the shapes in a sheet, you can select any one shape and then press control + A. That will select all the shapes and then press delete.

Comment: Now that I have excluded the Template sheet, it is no longer affected, only the other sheets. However on all other sheets, which are new sheets, old sheets with multiples were deleted, there are extra copies of shapes created each time the macro is run. The macro is standalone.

Comment: With the "Selection Pane" open, when I run the macro, I can literally see the number of objects doubling each time.

Comment: Try using this property `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False`

Comment: Thanks however I do want it to copy the objects. Row 1 needs to be updated (values and objects) on all sheets if changes are made to the Template sheet. I want the objects to replace the existing objects in the same way that values will replace existing values.